# Spring How to maintain logged in user without spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm building a simple project management web application and I'm having some problems finding the best practices for storing the current logged user without recurring to spring security.

I was thinking of creating a filter or maybe a interceptor to reduce code but I'm still struggling with how to actually store the user. Is it better to had a specific header to the request or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spring session` to maintain the login information in you app in a better way, there are various options available in spring to replace normal `HttpSession` like Spring Session JDBC.

See Here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-session